# I'm getting error during HA configuration for KVM on CentOS

Tags: centos7, kvm-virtualization, high-availability, iscsi, zimbra

After adding all nodes and resource agents in my cluster I'm[image] getting this error please someone suggest me something. Please take a look in the image-